# resultset is making problems when column name is integer

Tags: sql, resultset

I have a database which is storing temperature values so my database's column name are 100 150 200

Now the problem is when I trying to fetch values under column name 100 it shows error 
My query looks like

Select 100 from user where name='me';

Then
rs.get string("100"); this line gives errors

Can anyone plz suggest me how to retrieve values under these type of column names??

Comment: use rs["100"]; //try this

Comment: Looks like a poorly designed database.  Have you considered a normalized schema?  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL way to escape column names is to enclose within **double qoutes**.

```
SELECT "100" from user where name='me';
```

This is supported in most of DBMS - Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL and SQlite.

Apart from it , there are databse specific ways to escape column names

**SQL Server - Square brackets []**

```
SELECT [100] from user where name='me';
```

**MySQL - Backticks ``**

```
SELECT `100` from user where name='me';
```

Note :

- Double qoutes act as escaping reserved words in **MSSQL** when
  [**QUOTED_IDENTIFIER**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is ON.
- Double qoutes ac as escaping reserved words in **MySQL** if it is in ANSI
  mode

So for MSSQL , do first

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER;
```

Comment: I am using SQL  server 2010 and that [100] works only in server 2010 not in my page.... And I think that rs.get string also causes  problem

Comment: I know BT it gives error when I Im using it inside query

Answer (score 1):

If your query use a any keyword or numerical column name then use [] for MS-SQL and `` for MySQL.

MS-SQL:

```
Select [100] from user where name='me';
```

My-SQL:

```
Select `100` from user where name='me';
```